# Push Notification is not working PhoneGap Android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I am trying to implement push notification in Android-Phonegap. I am successfully getting following response - 1. deviceready event received 2. registering Android

but i am not getting Google Reg. ID. I am following the following source code  https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Please let me know if i am missing something. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

follow this link :-
http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/
and for GCM setting (api key,sender key) you have to create Google API project.
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html
start with 
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
To create Google API project:-
https://console.developers.google.com/project?utm_referrer=http:%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fgoogle%2Fgcm%2Fgs.html

Android phonegap push notification
http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/